# Problema con Vue Router cuando envío una ruta con una "Prop"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Tengo un problema con la nueva versión de Vue-Router cuando hago una ruta con una prop.

```
"vue-router": "^3.1.5".
```

Si la sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
<a v-bind:href="`/articlesone/${index}`">Article</a>
```

Me va a una página completamente en blanco. La única forma de que funcione adecuadamente es con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
 <router-link :to="{ name: 'articlesone', params: { id: index }}">Read</router-link>
```

Aún así, una vez que he ido a la página solicitada, cuando le doy a F5 o al botón de recargar del navegador me vuelve a aparecer la página en blanco.

Ni siquiera es un 404 ya que tengo habilitado un componente en router por si me sale este error.

¿Cual sería la sintaxis correcta?

Comment: Revisa la consola para ver el error

Comment: La consola no me devuelve ningún error, simplemente una página en blanco.